# edit through visual studio an msword file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, ms-office

i am trying a program that can edit an existing ms word document through an instant editing at a visual studio 2010 program but im having trouble. my codes:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim wd1 As Word.Application
    Dim wd1Doc As Word.Document
    wd1 = New Word.Application
    wd1.Visible = True

    wd1Doc = wd1.Documents.Add("C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\activity6\profile.dotx")

    With wd1Doc
        .FormFields("w_name").Range = TextBox1.Text
        .FormFields("w_age").Range = TextBox2.Text
    End With
    wd1 = Nothing
    wd1Doc = Nothing

End Sub
End Class
```

the errors says: "property range is read only"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. If you want to the the text of a `Range` object, you need to use its `.Text` property:

```
With wd1Doc
    .FormFields("w_name").Range.Text = TextBox1.Text
    .FormFields("w_age").Range.Text = TextBox2.Text
End With
```